# Explicit solution of SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Consider the SDE $$
dS_t = S_t^2 dB_t
$$
Find the explicit solution in the time interval $[0,T]$.

I am not sure whether this can be solved: alternatively show that $S_t >0 \, \; \; a.s$.